# How to split SASS files into multiple CDNs

Tags: css, sass, gulp, frameworks, cdn

Current situation:

We have 1 application that generates sass files, which is then obviously compiled into CSS and uploaded to 1 CDN location. This is done by "us" (the design team).

There are multiple applications that use this css CDN. This is done by the devs, who just import said CDN, ready to use. (To clarify: the solution can not involve anything on the dev-end.)

This one CDN contains

- basic stuff that all applications need (color variables, mixins, etc)
- application specific styling: meaning there are rootclasses (.application-1 {}, .application-2 {},...) that contains everything for that specific application, so it doesn't interfere with anything else

Now as you might imagine, that one CDN is becoming very bulky and every application is loading all styles for all applications which is unnecessary heavy.

So what we want:

- 1 CDN with the general stuff that every application will use
- multiple CDNs for application-specific stuff

The problem:
Since it's SASS that we use, I can't just say to gulp to generate separate files and be done with it because the specific SASS relies on the mixins and variables of the general SASS.

I hope this is clear, it's a tad difficult to explain properly. I'm hoping someone has had this same issue and can tell me how they solved it.

Comment: How do you mean, should the cdn handle sass files? 
And why cant gulp generate several files?

Comment: Hi, gulp can generate files ofcourse, but they won't compile because if I separate them and gulp tries to compile the SASS files for applicationX separately, it won't be able to find all the variables, mixins, or extends that are defined in the main files.

Comment: That depends on how your file structure looks like and how gulp is configured? 
You should be able to compile `main.scss` and `application.scss` to a separate `application.css`